# selenium 'X' mark doesn't close on python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to close image file on the website.

It seems like using javascript and result shows

**Process finished with exit code 0**

but it didn't close it. what is wrong with my code?
my code is below.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", driver.find_element_by_id('email_result'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you'r locating parent element of the `close icon image button` instead that's why you'r in trouble. You should try using `find_element_by_css_selector` to locate `close icon` as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#email_result > div.closeIcon').click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I could easily understand :)